# Uniform boundedness of functions in non-metrizable spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces

How can we define uniform boundedness of a function in a **non-metrizable space**?

---

For metric spaces, from Wikipedia ([Uniform boundedness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_boundedness)):

> *Let $Y$ be a **metric space** with metric $d$, then the set*
>
> $$\mathcal F=\{f_i: X \to Y, i\in I\}$$
>
> *is called **uniformly bounded** if there exists an element $a$ from $Y$ and a real number $M$ such that*
>
> $$d(f_i(x), a) \leq M \qquad \forall i \in I \quad \forall x \in X $$

Comment: If you have a topological vector space and a set $V$ you can say that $V$ is bounded if there is a neighborhood of $0$, say $U$, and a scalar $\lambda$ for which $V \subset \lambda U$.

Comment: Note that whether maps are uniformly bounded depends not just on the fact that $Y$ is metrizable but also (at least in part) on the specific metric chosen.  So it would be better to phrase the question as being about "spaces with some weaker structure than a metric" rather than about "non-metrizable spaces".

Comment: In any case, the answer is basically "we can't", unless you specify some additional structure on $Y$ which gives a notion of "bounded subset of $Y$".  Is there some particular reason you want to be able to define this?

Comment: Thank you giovanni and @EricWofsey. You're right, Eric. Uniform boundedness only makes sense on metrizable sets (I still wondering why it depends on the specific metric chosen). 
Anyway, I'll reword my question replacing "non-metrizable" with "bornological", following martini's anwser on non-metric spaces equipped with a bornology. Do you agree?
And no, I don't have a specific reason I wanted such a definition. I just got stuck in this concept while working on non related work 
and could not find it in any literature I had.

Comment: The choice of metric matters because, for instance, $\mathbb{R}$ and $(0,1)$ are homeomorphic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual notion for a space, where boundedness can be discussed is a *bornological* space, where we are given a family of sets, which we consider "small" or "bounded" in some sence. Recall

> **Definition 1**. Let $X$ be a set, a family $\beta \subseteq \def\P{\mathfrak P}\P(X)$ is called *bornology* on $X$, if the following holds
>   (i) $\bigcup \beta = X$ (every point lies in a bounded set)
>   (ii) If $A \subseteq B$ and $B \in \beta$, then $A \in \beta$ (subsets of bounded sets are bounded).
>   (iii) If $B_1, B_2 \in \beta$, then $B_1 \cup B_2 \in \beta$ (finite unions of bounded sets are bounded).
>   Elements of $\beta$ are called *($\beta$-)bounded sets*, the pair $(X,\beta)$ a *bornological space*.
>
> **Definition 2.** Let $(X,\beta_X)$, $(Y, \beta_Y)$ be bornological spaces, a map $f \colon X \to Y$ is called *bounded* (or *bornological*, as that is not your version of *bounded*), if $f[\beta_X]\subseteq \beta_Y$, that is if the image of bounded sets is bounded.

Examples include the following:

- For every set $X$, $\P(X)$ and $\mathfrak F(X) := \{A \in \P(X): A \text{ is finite}\}$ are bornologies on $X$.
- For a metric space $(X,d)$, the $d$-bounded sets in the classical sence 
  $$ \beta_d := \{A \in \P(X)\mid \exists a\in X,M: A \subseteq B_M(a)\} $$
  form a bornology.
- To give a more interesting example, we consider a topological vector space $X$. A set $B \subseteq X$ is called (von Neumann-)bounded, if it is absorbed by all neighbourhoods of zero, that is: 
  $$ \forall U \subseteq X: 0 \in \operatorname{int}U \implies \exists \lambda > 0 : B \subseteq \lambda U $$
  The in these sense bounded sets, form a bornology on $X$, and we have (as for normed spaces:

**Theorem**. *If $T \colon X \to Y$ is a continuous linear map between topological vector spaces, then it is bounded.*

In this realm, you can of course also discuss the uniform version of being bounded, just translate the metric version you have above:

> **Definition**. Let $(Y, \beta)$ be a bornological space, $X$ a set. A family of maps $f_i \colon X \to Y$ is called *uniformly bounded*, if there is a $B \in \beta$ such that $f_i[X]\subseteq B$, for all $i \in I$.

If you want to use that for a non-metric topological space (not that for metrizable spaces, the bornology does not depend only on the topology, but on the choice of the metric) $Y$, you have to say/define your bornology, that is to define what a bounded set in $Y$ is, examples are: $\P(X)$ (not very interesting so), $\mathfrak F(X)$ (makes a map bounded only if its image is finite) and (which in some sense gives Tien's example) and is a bornology if $Y$ is $T_1$: 
$$ \beta := \{ U\subseteq Y \mid \bar U \text{ is compact.}\} $$

Comment: Thank you, @martini. Your answer is enough for me. I think it's better I reword my question replacing "non-metrizable" with "bornological". Do you agree?